# Image Not Displaying On Window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

Here's my code so far. The image doesn't display on the window that's generated. I checked and it doesn't exceeds the limit of size or dimensions etc. What do you think the problem can be?

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
def Window():
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle("PyQt6 Activity")
    label=QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    label.setText("That's a text.")
    label.move(200,30)
    label2=QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    label2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("url.jpg"))
    window.setGeometry(100,100,500,500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
Window()
```

Comment: Did you try to put the full path to the image file?

Comment: Ensure that the path (which in your case is relative, and relative means that it's based to the working dir, not just the path of the script) is correct. The first thing to check is the result of [`QtGui.QPixmap("url.jpg").isNull()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#isNull): if it returns `True`, the path is not correct.